# How can you tell who access the root?

Tags: logging, freebsd

It's freebsd:

I want to find who type a certain command in root in it's history."xyz" for example.

Lets say you have person A B C D and E. All of whom have wheel access.

How can I know which person typed that command as root?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all sudo instances are logged so you can find the command with a date, time and username. I know you asked about bsd but I'm going to put the location for a few distros for completeness:

BSD:
`/var/logs/messages` (Note that BSD doesn't actually have sudo installed by default last I checked so you may have to look for the command, and who su'd to root immeditely before it was executed)
Debian-style distros:
`/var/log/auth.log`
RHEL-style distros: (what I'm on now)
`/var/log/secure`